# Counting all rows in a SQL Query with multiple left joins

Tags: mysql, sql, count, rows

I am trying to create a SQL query where I take in 3 tables, and count all the rows.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get a response from this query.

```
$sqlQuery ="SELECT COUNT(*)
  tblCampaignLists.CampaignListId,
  tblCampaignLists.ClientId,
  tblCampaignLists.CampaignId,
  tblCampaignLists.CampaignFilter,
  tblClients.ClientName,
  tblClients.ClientState,
  tblClients.ClientCreationDate,
  tblClients.ClientEmail, 
  tblClients.ClientAddressCounty,
  tblCampaigns.CampaignName,
  tblCampaigns.CampaignDescription,
  tblCampaigns.OrganisationId,
  tblCampaignFilters.FilterId,
  tblCampaignFilters.Section,
  tblCampaignFilters.TitleIds,
  tblCampaignFilters.FeatureIds,
  tblCampaignFilters.EditionIds,
  tblCampaignFilters.NotInEditionId
FROM
  tblCampaignLists
  LEFT JOIN tblClients ON tblClients.ClientId = tblCampaignLists.ClientId
  LEFT JOIN tblCampaigns ON tblCampaigns.CampaignId = tblCampaignLists.CampaignId
  LEFT JOIN tblCampaignFilters ON tblCampaignFilters.FilterId = tblCampaignLists.CampaignFilter


What can I do to get the number of rows?
```

Comment: Remove the columns from the SELECT list: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`

Comment: Since your query is a variable, you probably can get the number of rows from wherever you are executing the query

Answer (score 0):

Only use count:

```
$sqlQuery ="SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  tblCampaignLists
  LEFT JOIN tblClients ON tblClients.ClientId = tblCampaignLists.ClientId
  LEFT JOIN tblCampaigns ON tblCampaigns.CampaignId = tblCampaignLists.CampaignId
  LEFT JOIN tblCampaignFilters ON tblCampaignFilters.FilterId = tblCampaignLists.CampaignFilter"
```